# What does this function declaration mean? Function name and its argument are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript/jquery and trying to understand a .js file of wordpress plugin. Please give me some explanations for better understanding its fundamentals. My questions are about how the plugin author declares functions and calls them along with their arguments :

1. According to the given code example, from the first line what are the benefits of using `a` (...function(a){...) instead of `$`, because I've noticed that I can access elements by using both of them ; `a(...)` and `$(...)`.
2. The 2nd line makes me confused. Why the function name `e` is the same as its first argument.
3. The 4th line makes me more confused. What does `i=a(i)` mean ?
4. The 5th line, from `e.result` what is this `e` referred to (to the function `e` or to its first argument). Also, what does `===!0` mean ?
5. My last question : I've seen that the author tried to access `e.result`, `e.error`, and `e.message`. What are they ? Event object properties ? Because I haven't found their definitions and usages yet.

The attached code example is from the first few lines of .js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a){
   function e(e,i){
     a(".lwa-loading").remove(),
     i=a(i),
     e.result===!0 ? statement1 : statement2;
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: minimised/obfuscated code - it has no particular meaning

Comment: @JaromandaX i tought it was some kind of recursivity at first, never saw such a thing before

Comment: it's meant to confuse, I guess, hiding what it's doing in plain sight :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 It doesn't use `$` incase `$` is defined by another framework.  `a` is passed in the parameters.
See: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

2 `e` will be used as the variable within the function.  As long as the outer function `e` isn't called within itself, there's no conflict.  As stated in the comments, `e` is used as the code has been "minified".

3 `i=a(i)` is the same as `i = $(i)` (remember `a` = `$`) - it wraps the argument `i` to ensure that it's a jquery object.   Javascript isn't strongly typed, so this can change a DOM variable to a jquery variable or keeps it as a jquery variable if it was already.  It gives more flexibility to what the code can be called with.

4 it always uses the closest scoped variable, in this case it will be the parameter in `e(e,i)`

5 depends on how `e(e,i)` is called - which isn't included in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

1. The argument provided to the document.ready event handler is an instance of jQuery. You can use this to alias jQuery itself within the scope of that function. This is that's being done in this case with the `a` variable - it's now a reference to `jQuery`. This is useful in cases where you have multiple frameworks fighting for control of the `$` variable.
2. From the look of the code it has been minified. This is why the variable and function names have been shortened as much as possible in order to reduce filesize. This is not human-readable code. I'd suggest finding a non-minified version if you want to fully understand the logic.
3. `i = a(i)` means assign `i` to the result of calling the `a()` function within the original value of `i` as an argument
4. `e` is a reference that whatever the first argument of the `e()` function was. Without seeing how the function is called I cannot tell you exactly what it is.
5. They are properties of the `e` argument provided to the function. It could be an POJS object, and Event object or something else entirely. Without seeing the calling context it's impossible to say for certain.